# 12.04 Ubuntu install failure or hardware issue?

Tags: installation

When installing Ubuntu 12.04 the install feature asks if I want to remove the old OS (Windows XP), I choose yes, but when the install finishes and restarts the computer it can't load the Ubuntu OS and when I choose to install it from disk again and then put it onto the HDD it asks if I want to remove the old OS again!!??

Is this a hardware issue/software issue? Is it ever going to work or am I wasting my time?

So far, I've tried reinstalling it... and checked all the hardware is connceted correctly and reads it ok.

Hardware details: Celeron 2.66GHz, 1.2gb ram, 40gb hdd with an 80gb slave (having trouble reading that one properly), Ubuntu 12.4, 30.2 gb free on master HDD.

Also Ubuntu works fine if running off the CD/DVD.

after fiddling with it for a whole day i now get an error:

GRUB loading stage1.5read error

really need some help guys its not the HDD its something else. im brand new to ubuntu and i cant even get it to work. also this is the first computer ive ever built ive known how to do it for ages but never practiced.

Comment: What's you PC/Notebook Manufacturer?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu from the LiveCD while Windows is running? If so, you cannot remove the host OS (Windows). Boot from the CD instead and reinstall. That will give you the option to remove the old OS and set up LVM.

Comment: no windows doesnt work. when it tries to load the win OS it has an OS read error (best guess is a key issue as its a different motherboard and Processor in there.and to answer the second part all i am doing is running from the CD and trying to install to the HDD over the old XP OS.... it finishes the install but says there is a read error trying to install on the 80gb drive now... changed the strapping on the drives

Comment: @mat Please, take a look at [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/62483), follow the methods mentioned there, and tell us your results.

Comment: @ Lucio i dont understand ANY of that!! i am brand new to ubuntu.
if you could explain how to do it in a moron proof way then please do cos i dont understand.

Comment: @Mat Do you have an Ubuntu LiveCD? You can boot from it? Then you have to *read the [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/62483)*, it is not so hard if you take a time reading and trying. Try with that and tell me later..

Answer (score 0):

Try and format your disk in the Bios... And install Ubuntu from a CD/DVD or USB-bootable. This way you are surtain that the old OS is uninstalled.

Update: In your PCs Bios the formatting option should be under security/Disk Sanitizer.

Here's a link providing step by step instructions on how to wipe your HDD outside of windows:

[How to Wipe a Hard Drive](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/wipe-hard-drive.htm)

So I've been searching the net for an answer regarding your error message above and found this:

[Grub Loading stage1.5Read Error](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1228813)

Comment: I'm pretty sure no **all** BIOSes have this *feature*, it would be better if you add instructions to do that in an OS.

Comment: Have you ever tried formatting a Disk while the OS was still running?

Comment: think the bios is too old to have that feature in it but i will check thank you for the idea never thought of that myself! just tried plugging the drive into a comp that i know works.... but found out the motherboard is too new and has no IDE ports on it!

Comment: this is not an answer i need something else

Comment: Did you manage to get rid of Win XP?

Comment: no but it wont load it anyway.... and i cant access it but it keeps asking me to remove it when i install ubuntu